# Где можно посмотреть исходники OpenMP в Visual Studio 2012 C++

Tags: c++, openmp

У меня есть задание - разобрать работу библиотеки omp.h. Есть ли где-нибудь исходники этой библиотеки, чтобы можно было посмотреть ее реализацию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenMP это API, т.е. это стандарт. Каждый из разработчиков имеет свою реализацию. Я думаю реализация OpenMP для Visual Studio является закрытой и исходники не доступны. Исходники могут быть доступны для других реализаций [например для GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/gomp/).